# Using Gifs as Wallpaper on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, desktop-background, gif

So I found this program called LiveWallpaper that has a variety of Gifs to use as Wallpapers and I think it's alright... But I want a bit more variety and was hoping there's a way to either add more Gifs to it or to see if someone could recommend an alternative program that well let me do what I'd like to do on my computer.